# Visual Studio 2008: Jump between code marked as incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Are there shortcut keys to jump between code marked as incorrect (a red wavy line) by intellisense? I know F8 can be used to jump between errors after compilation, that's not what I want.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't know about a shortcut for that, but go View->Other Windows->Error List and get the error list panel, it will show up next to the console. Compile (F7), and all the red marks (errors) will appear there. Just click on them to navigate trhough.

Comment: @David Menard: I don't want to compile, this is a long process here. Intellisense already shows me errors I can fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View.NextError and View.PreviousError commands work just fine to jump between errors detected by IntelliSense on my machine.  Not sure what your problem might be, do verify that these errors are listed in the Error List window.  Tapping your foot a few times to allow the IntelliSense parser to catch up might be necessary.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that intellisense errors do appear after a while in Error List window. I thought this list was populated only during compilation.